# Exporting Custom Magento Field via Export Customers

Tags: php, magento, csv, export

I have created an extension that adds an additional field to the customers accounts, this works great - data is saved - all good. But...

We need to use System -> Import/Export -> Export. When I select "Customers" from the dropdown list Magento gives me the following error:

[image: Custom field error]

My attribute is added as it does appear in the eav_attribute table. The only other question I could find on something very similar to this just told me to look at: \app\code\core\Mage\Customer\Model\Convert\Parser\Customer.php

I understand at this point Magento builds a grid in the Admin Panel allowing you to select which fields to export - but is this handled by the `unparse()` function in `\Parser\Customer.php` - or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the Magento IRC the root of the problem has been found.

My attribute was in the eav_attribute table, however on that row in the field 'source_model' was the value '(NULL)'.

To solve this I simply made this cell empty so no model or null value was specified. Customer's now import and export successfully.

Hope this helps others!